# In App purchase - Removing Ads, Need external Server or not

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to develop an iOS app where I want to display the ads and want user to remove ads through In App purchase.

I don't have any external server where I can store the details since there is no registration in the app.

So, is it necessary to have a server to store the details or we can do it without any server by just adding buy and restore options.

Comment: You can use a server to validate the purchase in case of fraud, but this is optional. You can simply store the purchase in the keychain and provide a restore option to cater for different devices & reinstalls

Comment: @Paulw11 you said very clearly.